# How do I get the video url with ytdl-core?

Tags: discord.js, ytdl

```
const { YTSearcher } = require('ytsearcher');
 
const searcher = new YTSearcher({
    key: config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY,
    revealed: true
});

let result = await searcher.search(args.join(" "), { type: "video" })

            var songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(result.first.url)
            var song = {
                title: songInfo.videoDetails.title,
                url: songInfo.videoDetails.video_url
            };
```

I'm using ytdl-core to play music using a discord bot, when I try to play a song it sends the error "Cannot read property 'url' of underfined"

Comment: Maybe it just didn't find any results. Try making sure `result.first` exists before getting the info.

Comment: @Lioness100 I'm pretty sure it found the result because the title part doesn't send errors